# Loopback: How to include related model during login?

Tags: loopbackjs

I am posting the username and password to the following url:

```
http://myapi.com/api/users/login?include[0]=user&include[1][user]=customer
```

Login goes fine, but only the user is included. How can I include the customer model (which has a one-to-one relationship with user) as well?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add after remote hook, which can modify your response after login endpoint was called and before the response object is sent to the user. Not usre if that's the best possible approach though

```
User.afterRemote('login', function (ctx, result, next) {
     // the rest of the code
     next();
 });
```